# Is it possible to initiate a 2 dimensional array of SizedBox (as an example, I need some kind of square) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, desktop-application

I want to program a chess game in Flutter so first I need to make my own board. For that, I thought I can initiate a 2 dimension array of SizedBox-es (again, not necessarily) and color it just like a real chess board.
But is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better option is to add a gridView like this:

```
GridView.builder(
                        itemCount: 64,
                        gridDelegate:
                            SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                crossAxisCount: 8,
                                crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                                mainAxisSpacing: 4.0),
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Container(
                            color: index%2 == 0 ? Colors.white : Colors.black
                          );
                        },
                      )
```

If you have `SizedBox` instead, it will be difficult for you to add color, coin image, and alignment etc

Answer (score 2):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can directly use package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_chess_board or reference it's source code 
code snippet of `buildChessBoard` 
https://github.com/deven98/flutter_chess_board/blob/c8042f2aa499158c10b87aca339a9a19198ce2f3/lib/src/chess_board.dart#L182

```
var whiteSquareList = [
  [
    "a8",
    "b8",
    "c8",
    "d8",
    "e8",
    "f8",
    "g8",
    "h8",
...
Widget buildChessBoard() {
    return Column(
      children: widget.whiteSideTowardsUser
          ? whiteSquareList.map((row) {
              return ChessBoardRank(
                children: row,
              );
            }).toList()
          : whiteSquareList.reversed.map((row) {
              return ChessBoardRank(
                children: row.reversed.toList(),
              );
            }).toList(),
    );
  } 
...
class ChessBoardRank extends StatelessWidget {
  /// The list of squares in the rank
  final List<String> children;

  ChessBoardRank({this.children});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Row(
        children: children
            .map(
              (squareName) => BoardSquare(squareName: squareName),
            )
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

working demo

[image]

full example code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_chess_board/src/chess_board.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ChessBoard(
              onMove: (move) {
                print(move);
              },
              onCheckMate: (color) {
                print(color);
              },
              onDraw: () {},
              size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              enableUserMoves: true,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```